# Why do some profiles on the LinkedIn API have numbers in their names?

Tags: web-services, api, linkedin-api

When I retrieve users from the LinkedIn API, a small number of them have a number (of connections, I guess) in their names?
For example:

```
 http://www.linkedin.com/pub/riccardo-bertaggia-1000/2/195/441
```

is:

```
 Riccardo Bertaggia 1000+
```

consistently with in the API and in the web page. Is this something that people add or is it generated by LinkedIn internally?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provide, they have manually added the 1000+ to their name. To retrieve the actual number of connections, you'd want to pull the `num-connections` and `num-connections-capped` [fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields) from the [Profile API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api).